# Using flot with NPM, React, and Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to use flot in a Node.js React project. Flot will not import. I receive the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _jquery2.default.plot is not a function
```

Which is functionally the same as

```
$.plot is not a function
```

Here is my component code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import flot from 'flot';
import React from 'react';
import component from './jsxComponent';

const LinePlot = component('LinePlot', {
    componentDidMount () {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), [[0, 5], [1, 10], [2, 15], [3, 20]]);
    }
}, function ({someParams}) {
    return(
        <div id="placeholder"></div>
    );
});

export default LinePlot;
```

npm install was successful, Flot is included in my /node_modules/ directory, and I'm including jquery before flot in the component code above.

```
console.log(flot); //returns an empty object (Object {})
```

Has anyone had any success with Node+NPM+Flot before? If so, how did you import it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't seem to exist anymore on NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/flot)

Comment: Maybe try this https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1381

Comment: Looking at the repo, it doesn't seem to be exported as either a commonJS or AMD module either.

Comment: @PI. I tried updating my dependencies to include

`"Flot": "git+https://github.com/flot/flot.git#v0.8.3"`

and ran npm install again, along with changing LinePlot.js to 

`import Flot from 'Flot';`

but I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

I use Gulp with babel, browserify and browserify-shim modules, this works for me:

**package.json**

```
"browser": {
  "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "flot": "./node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.js"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "$",
  "flot": {
    "exports": "flot",
    "depends": [
      "jquery:jQuery"
    ]
}
```

**main.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'flot';

$.plot($("#placeholder"), [ [[0, 0], [1, 1]] ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that you're importing the actual module, rather than just including it in the file by `import 'flot'`. I assume this, because that's how every project seems to be doing it.

That said, in your use case it may not be the best option to manipulate the DOM via an external library (jQuery), which using React. I know it's not going to break anything in this case in particular, but there are some React libraries with clean and simple APIs that can do the same (and more).

I would give [Recharts](http://recharts.org) a try.